# What are the key differences between Terraria and Starbound

Tags: terraria, starbound

I'm thinking about buying Starbound, but at the moment it just looks like a Terraria with aliens and different items.

I kinda liked Terraria but I don't wanna spend money on the same game with only like 3 differences. So could one of you guys explain to me what the big differences between these two games?

Comment: I do not believe those questions are duplicates. I do, however, think this question should be closed, at least until edited. How do you define "Key differences"? You already included two in your questions... it's got aliens and different items. It's not clear exactly what you're asking for, and the list could either be as short those two or as long as an item-by-item difference, depending on exactly what it is you are looking for. I'm currently voting to close as Too Broad. I may not have selected the right reason, but I think in its current form, this question invites too much discussion.

Comment: I just wondered whether there are big differences that could reinvent the game or at least make it different, or if there are only these small things. As I already said I don't want to buy  a game that's basically the same as another except for 3 things. And i'm not really a person that wants to spend 15 Bucks let's say different races (that are purely cosmetic).

Comment: @Jutschge That sounds a little too close to a game rec for comfort.  On the other hand, game comparison MIGHT be okay.  It's in a very grey area.  The answer is mostly covered by the linked question, though if I have to make a recommendation to find out how different it is, you could watch a few videos of the gameplay to see how it compares.

Comment: If you can narrow this down to specific differences you are looking for, we might have an answerable question here.  Asking how two games, completely unrelated, are different is a huge topic.  If all you're looking for is basic information on Starbound, well, that's what their website is for.

Comment: @Jutschge For what it's worth, for me, Starbound basically plays like Terarria modded to have some extra features. The core gameplay is still the same... you run around, explore, dig, and craft better and better items, and kill bosses. However, for me, that's totally worth the $15. I don't know if that's worth $15 to you, though. That's why I was asking for some question clarification... I'm not sure exactly what information you are looking for so that you can properly make your decision. I also just voted to reopen because I disagree with my previous close vote. :P

Comment: Considering that Zibbobz was able to provide a perfectly good answer to this question, I'd suggest that the hold be removed.

Comment: @Fambida An accepted answer does not mean the question is acceptable.  They are two different things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a lot of differences between the two games.

- Races that are not Human - Starbound has 6 playable races, with a seventh to be released in the future.
- Space Exploration - You are not limited to exploring one planet in Starbound.  In fact, as soon as you have the fuel you need to pilot your spaceship (coal), you can leave your starting world and explore any planet you want.
- Very Different NPC Interaction - You will sometimes come across NPC generators that will create merchants, doctors and other NPCS that act like Terraria NPCS, but for the most part, NPCS are found on worlds, and can be hostile or non-hostile, offer merchant services, and are remarkably chill about you looting their house for all its valuables but VERY touchy about you holding a sword.
- Different Mining System - You can mine much wider spaces in Starbound, especially once you get a pick (the multitool is useful, but weak).
- Survival Mechanics - Unlike in Terraria, you actually have to eat regular meals and keep warm, or you will die.  Heat sources are easy enough to craft (though you'll need better ways to stay warm on colder planets), and food can be a little troublesome to come across, but it is an interesting challenge nontheless.

Of course, there is one very key difference right now between Starbound and Terraria that is very important to consider.

**Starbound is still in Beta**

And it's still a somewhat buggy Beta, with clipping issues and game-format-changing fixes and patches being applied as the Beta progresses.  There is a certain 'unfinished' feel to it right now.  Whereas Terraria has had years and years to not only be a fully released and finished game, but to have numerous patches, updates, and content additions added onto it, making it much more polished and mature.

So if you are still interested in Starbound, keep in mind that it is still in Beta, and still in the early phases of being improved.  A lot of the "higher tech" content that will set it apart from Terraria has not really been implemeneted yet (there are very few blueprints, very few high-tech crafting recipes, and what is there is still being improved upon), but it is forthcoming.

There are a few other minor differences here and there, but these are some of the more major differences between the two games.